# Why/When in Python does `x==y` call `y.__eq__(x)`?

Tags: python, comparison, operator-overloading

The Python docs clearly state that `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`.  However it seems that under many circumstances, the opposite is true.  Where is it documented when or why this happens, and how can I work out for sure whether my object's `__cmp__` or `__eq__` methods are going to get called.

Edit: Just to clarify, I know that `__eq__` is called in preferecne to `__cmp__`, but I'm not clear why `y.__eq__(x)` is called in preference to `x.__eq__(y)`, when the latter is what the docs state will happen.

```
>>> class TestCmp(object):
...     def __cmp__(self, other):
...         print "__cmp__ got called"
...         return 0
... 
>>> class TestEq(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         print "__eq__ got called"
...         return True
... 
>>> tc = TestCmp()
>>> te = TestEq()
>>> 
>>> 1 == tc
__cmp__ got called
True
>>> tc == 1
__cmp__ got called
True
>>> 
>>> 1 == te
__eq__ got called
True
>>> te == 1
__eq__ got called
True
>>> 
>>> class TestStrCmp(str):
...     def __new__(cls, value):
...         return str.__new__(cls, value)
...     
...     def __cmp__(self, other):
...         print "__cmp__ got called"
...         return 0
... 
>>> class TestStrEq(str):
...     def __new__(cls, value):
...         return str.__new__(cls, value)
...     
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         print "__eq__ got called"
...         return True
... 
>>> tsc = TestStrCmp("a")
>>> tse = TestStrEq("a")
>>> 
>>> "b" == tsc
False
>>> tsc == "b"
False
>>> 
>>> "b" == tse
__eq__ got called
True
>>> tse == "b"
__eq__ got called
True
```

Edit: From Mark Dickinson's answer and comment it would appear that:

1. Rich comparison overrides `__cmp__`
2. `__eq__` is it's own `__rop__` to it's `__op__` (and similar for `__lt__`, `__ge__`, etc)
3. If the left object is a builtin or new-style class, and the right is a subclass of it, the right object's `__rop__` is tried before the left object's `__op__`

This explains the behaviour in the`TestStrCmp` examples.  `TestStrCmp` is a subclass of `str` but doesn't implement its own `__eq__` so the `__eq__` of `str` takes precedence in both cases (ie `tsc == "b"` calls `b.__eq__(tsc)` as an `__rop__` because of rule 1).

In the `TestStrEq` examples, `tse.__eq__` is called in both instances because `TestStrEq` is a subclass of `str` and so it is called in preference.

In the `TestEq` examples, `TestEq` implements `__eq__` and `int` doesn't so `__eq__` gets called both times (rule 1).

But I still don't understand the very first example with `TestCmp`.  `tc` is not a subclass on `int` so AFAICT `1.__cmp__(tc)` should be called, but isn't.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're missing a key exception to the usual behaviour:  when the right-hand operand is an instance of a subclass of the class of the left-hand operand, the special method for the right-hand operand is called first.

See the documentation at:

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules

and in particular, the following two paragraphs:

> For objects `x` and `y`, first
>   `x.__op__(y)` is tried. If this is not
>   implemented or returns
>   `NotImplemented`, `y.__rop__(x)` is
>   tried. If this is also not implemented
>   or returns `NotImplemented`, a
>   TypeError exception is raised. But see
>   the following exception:
>
> Exception to the previous item: if the
>   left operand is an instance of a
>   built-in type or a new-style class,
>   and the right operand is an instance
>   of a proper subclass of that type or
>   class and overrides the base’s
>   `__rop__()` method, the right
>   operand’s `__rop__()` method is tried
>   before the left operand’s `__op__()`
>   method.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden:  Thanks for the formatting fixes!  I'll try to remember blockquote next time.

Comment: Nice one, however I thought, (but am not sure), that all `__rop__` methods were deprecated.  Also I'm not using any of them.

Comment: Agreed that you're not using any `__rop__` methods.  The comparison methods are special in this respect:  `__eq__` is its own reverse, so read `__eq__` for both `__op__` and `__rop__`.  (Similarly, `__ne__` is its own reverse, `__le__` is the reverse of `__ge__`, etc.)

Others have commented before (correctly, IMO) that the documentation could use some work here.

I'm almost certain that the `__rop__` methods aren't deprecated!

Comment: If you're right then that's the answer I would accept. Have you got any evidence that this is true?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__.  The fourth paragraph starts:  "There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods [...] rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection."  Or were you asking for evidence that the `__rop__` methods aren't deprecated?

Comment: You're right, and that definitely could do with clarifying.  I've read that page several times now, and it hadn't sunk in that it's saying that `__lt__` is the `__rop__` of `__gt__`.  Also isn't that wrong?  Shouldn't `__lt__` be the `__rop__` of `__ge__`?  IE `(2<2)==(not(2>=2))`

Comment: Also we still haven't quite explained the very first example: `1 == tc`.  The only explanation I can see ATM for that is that a subclass of `object` counts as a subclass of any builtin for the purposes of operator overloading.

Comment: No, I think it's right: `__lt__` is the `__rop__` of `__gt__`.  There's no logical negation going on;  just a reversal of the arguments.  The translation is: `x.__lt__(y)` <=> `x < y` <=> `y > x` <=> `y.__gt__(x)`.

Comment: The rules for `__cmp__` (especially in combination with rich comparisons) are truly hairy, and I don't think they're even properly documented anywhere, except in the source.  (PyObject_RichCompare in the Objects/object.c file is the main place to look, if you feel inclined.)  In the `1 == tc` example, neither side implements `__eq__`, so we fall back on `__cmp__`.  `int.__cmp__` can only handle comparisons with other integers, so it's ignored (not even called), and your `TestCmp.__cmp__` method gets called instead.

Getting rid of `__cmp__` in py3k was a Very Good Thing.  :)

Comment: Well, I've awarded you the answer for sheer depth of answering.  I guess it appears the real answer to my question is "no one really knows".  Let's hope it works out a lot clearer in Py3k.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization), it states:

> [`__cmp__` is c]alled by comparison operations if rich comparison (see above) is not defined.

`__eq__` is a rich comparison method and, in the case of `TestCmp`, is not defined, hence the calling of `__cmp__`

Comment: But `str.__eq__` is defined, so presumably `TestStrCmp.__eq__` is defined (inherited).

Comment: You are right that `__eq__` overrides `__cmp__`, but that was not the surprising behaviour.  The surprise was that it calls it on the right object not the left one.  (I've updated the question to clarify this a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Is this not documented in the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)? Just from a quick look there, it looks like `__cmp__` is ignored when `__eq__`, `__lt__`, etc are defined. I'm understanding that to include the case where `__eq__` is defined on a parent class. `str.__eq__` is already defined so `__cmp__` on its subclasses will be ignored. `object.__eq__` etc are not defined so `__cmp__` on its subclasses will be honored.

In response to the clarified question:

> I know that `__eq__` is called in
>   preferecne to `__cmp__`, but I'm not
>   clear why `y.__eq__(x)` is called in
>   preference to `x.__eq__(y)`, when the
>   latter is what the docs state will
>   happen.

Docs say `x.__eq__(y)` will be called first, but it has the option to return `NotImplemented` in which case `y.__eq__(x)` is called. I'm not sure why you're confident something different is going on here.

Which case are you specifically puzzled about? I'm understanding you just to be puzzled about the `"b" == tsc` and `tsc == "b"` cases, correct? In either case, `str.__eq__(onething, otherthing)` is being called. Since you don't override the `__eq__` method in TestStrCmp, eventually you're just relying on the base string method and it's saying the objects aren't equal.

Without knowing the implementation details of `str.__eq__`, I don't know whether `("b").__eq__(tsc)` will return `NotImplemented` and give tsc a chance to handle the equality test. But even if it did, the way you have TestStrCmp defined, you're still going to get a false result.

So it's not clear what you're seeing here that's unexpected.

Perhaps what's happening is that Python is preferring `__eq__` to `__cmp__` if it's defined on *either* of the objects being compared, whereas you were expecting `__cmp__` on the leftmost object to have priority over `__eq__` on the righthand object. Is that it?

Comment: Having played with this a bit more, I think you are right that `__eq__` is preferred on either object in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `__eq__()` is a so-called “rich comparison” method, and is called for comparison operators in preference to `__cmp__()` below. `__cmp__()` is called if "rich comparison" is not defined.

So in A == B:
    If `__eq__()` is defined in A it will be called
    Else `__cmp__()` will be called

`__eq__()` defined in 'str' so your `__cmp__()` function was not called.

The same rule is for `__ne__(), __gt__(), __ge__(), __lt__()` and `__le__()` "rich comparison" methods.