# Does python coerce types when doing operator overloading?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a = str('5')
b = int(5)
a == b
# False
```

But if I make a subclass of `int`, and reimplement `__cmp__`:

```
class A(int):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return super(A, self).__cmp__(other)
a = str('5')
b = A(5)
a == b
# TypeError: A.__cmp__(x,y) requires y to be a 'A', not a 'str'
```

Why are these two different?  Is the python runtime catching the TypeError thrown by `int.__cmp__()`, and interpreting that as a `False` value?  Can someone point me to the bit in the 2.x cpython source that shows how this is working?

Comment: On a side note: you know that `__cmp__` was deprecated ages ago? You should implement rich-comparison functions.

Comment: Yes, this came up when I was trying to figure out if I should raise an exception or return NotImplemented in an implementation of __eq__.  I wanted to see what the builtin Python classes did, and found this example that seemed inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation isn't completely explicit on this point, but see [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> If both are numbers, they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but arbitrarily. You can control comparison behavior of objects of non-built-in types by defining a `__cmp__` method or rich comparison methods like `__gt__`, described in section Special method names.

This (particularly the implicit contrast between "objects of different types" and "objects of non-built-in types") suggests that the normal process of actually calling comparison methods is skipped for built-in types: if you try to compare objects of two dfferent (and non-numeric) built-in types, it just short-circuits to an automatic False.

Answer (score 3):

A comparison decision tree for `a == b` looks something like:

- python calls `a.__cmp__(b)`

  - `a` checks that `b` is an appropriate type
  - if `b` is an appropriate type, return `-1`, `0`, or `+1`
  - if `b` is not, return `NotImplented`
- if `-1`, `0`, or `+1` returned, python is done; otherwise
- if NotImplented returned, try
- `b.__cmp__(a)`

  - `b` checks that `a` is an appropriate type
  - if `a` is an appropriate type, return `-1`, `0`, or `+1`
  - if `a` is not, return `NotImplemented`
- if `-1`, `0`, or `+1` returned, python is done; otherwise
- if NotImplented returned again, the answer is `False`

Not an exact answer, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your problem right, you need something like:

```
>>> class A(int):
...     def __cmp__(self, other):
...         return super(A, self).__cmp__(A(other)) # <--- A(other) instead of other
... 
>>> a = str('5')
>>> b = A(5)
>>> a == b
True
```

**Updated**

Regarding to 2.x cpython source, you can find reason for this result in `typeobject.c` in function `wrap_cmpfunc` which actually checks two things: given compare function is a `func` and `other` is subtype for `self`.

```
if (Py_TYPE(other)->tp_compare != func &&
    !PyType_IsSubtype(Py_TYPE(other), Py_TYPE(self))) {
// ....
}
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question at all.  I think OP recognizes that he can coerce the type of other to make the comparison work.  The question is *why does he have to?*  Why doesn't `__cmp__` see that the types aren't the same and return `False` right away?

Comment: The question is why are there two different results, not how to make `str` and `int` compare.

Comment: The subtype check is done to allow subclasses to completely reimplement operators, otherwise doing `A == B` and `B == A` could yield to different results if `B` is a subclass of `A`.(see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281222/why-when-in-python-does-x-y-call-y-eq-x) question and answer.

Comment: I think it's a combination of that `wrap_cmpfunc` in `typeobjec.c`, and `do_cmp` and the `*_3way_compare` functions in object.c.  Based on what I see when actually running the code, `do_cmp` runs first, and can short-circuit before calling `int.__cmp__()`, aka `wrap_cmpfunc`.  Which is why calling `int.__cmp__()` directly raises an exception, but the `==` operator does not.