# Comparison of object with built-in type

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class called `IntField` which encapsulates a integer from a database (not really relevant). I'd like to use an instance of `IntField` for evaluating expressions using `eval`.

The classes looks like:

```
class DbField(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print "comparing {} ({}) with {} ({})".format(self, type(self), other, type(other))
        if type(self.value) == type(other):
            return self.value.__cmp__(other)
        elif type(self) == type(other):
            return self.value.__cmp__(other.value)
        raise ValueError("cannot compare {} and {}".format(type(self), type(other)))

class IntField(DbField):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(IntField, self).__init__(int(value))

a = IntField(-2)
b = IntField(-2)

print "a=", a
print "b=", b

print "b == -1 ", b == -1
print "b == a ", b == a
print "a == b ", a == b
print "-1 == b ", -1 == b
```

What I want to achieve in the base class is to allow the custom object to be comparable with another custom object of the same type, but also with the builtin type; I want to be able to do `IntField == IntField` or `IntField == int`.

I expect that `IntField.__cmp__()` of the first object to be called for these comparisons, which is happening. But I'm being puzzled about what happens for `int == IntField`. Seems that in this case, the `IntField.__cmp__()` method is also being called, instead of `int`'s . Can someone explain how the comparison against built-in types works?

Comment: Ok, it seems I found the answer, it's been asked before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281222/why-when-in-python-does-x-y-call-y-eq-x